# (eAccelerator) Meaning of shared memory

Tags: php

Im trying to cache the opcode in hard disk.

But Im not sure what the meaning of "shared memory"

**disk_only** cache data on disk
(I know this means cache data on hard disk)

**shm_only** cache data in shared memory
(I still confuse about this. Is "shared memory" means swap, or RAM?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Mwebe - the PHP folks on Stackoverflow will jump at the opportunity to clarify this. 
@Chopper3 It's quite refreshing to be pushing a question over to SO for a change. :)

Comment: ISN'T it! it *never* works out like does it!

Answer (score 2):

Shared memory is memory area, which multiple processes can access. It`s is just RAM, only specific thing - OS allows multiple proccesses to access it .